# Looking for a USB-C hub with power delivery where the hub sits by the power supply (for MacBook Pro)

Tags: hub, usb-c

I am looking for a hub where I can plug the power supply, a couple USB accessories and FROM the hub run a long cable to the computer.

So the hub has to sit right by the power supply and, on my desk, I'd have only a single cable going to the computer.

But all hubs I find are like this:

[image]

They have a short cable that goes to the computer and expect the power delivery to come from the longer cable. They're designed to sit by the computer, which is exactly the opposite of what I'd like.

I've tried one and it didn't charge when used in a "reversed" configuration.

Do they exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if docks with longer cables exist, but you can always use an extention chord like this one: [https://www.amazon.com/DISDIM-Thunderbolt-Extension-Charging-Compatible/dp/B075MBS6JY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075MBS6JY)

Comment: I guess that could work with many hubs in this case; I haven't seen extensions like this in any stores, but it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Would your issue be solved with a hub that has a replaceble/removable cable
[like this one?](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CGCSQLF)